# Editing values in DataTable with sorting active sorts table on input

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

This question is related to the following Bug Report: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/3468

I have a `VDataTable` with sortable column headers and various input elements (`VTextField` and `VSelect`).

Editing the input elements with sorting active on a specific column edits the model. This causes the table to re-order while typing (in the `VTextField`) or when selecting a different value (in the `VSelect`).

Ideally the table should only re-order once the appropriate column header is clicked. In other words, the table shouldn't automatically sort but only manually sort.

[This Pen](https://codepen.io/GPBuffo/pen/VxOyQP) illustrates the issue. Make sure sorting on countries is selected when testing the behaviour with the `VSelect`

Comment: Were you ever able to fix this issue? Or is it still an open issue?

Comment: @SvenHakvoort It's still open unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with a hack to get around this behavior. See the following fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/Loh5kyzt/

To exercise the fiddle, click on of the check boxes. Then sort on the "Chkd" column. Then check a currently unchecked row input box. The rows won't move around again until you sort once again on a column.

The behavior was very annoying at first in my fiddle; I thought I had written a bug. I am cross posting my fiddle to the issue reported in Vue.

JS Code

```
Vue.component('data-row', {
  props: ['row', 'index', 'currentSortCol'],
  template: `
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" @click="$emit('checkee', $event.target.checked, index)"/></td>
      <td>{{ row.a }}</td>
      <td>{{ row.b }}</td>
      <td>{{ row.c }}</td>
      <td>{{ row.d }}</td>
      <td>{{ row.e }}</td>
      <td>{{ row.chkd }}</td>
    </tr>
  `,
});

Vue.component('head-row', {
  props: [],
  template: `
    <thead>
      <th>Delete</th>
      <th @click="$emit('sort', 'a')">Col A</th>
      <th @click="$emit('sort', 'b')">Col B</th>
      <th @click="$emit('sort', 'c')">Col C</th>
      <th @click="$emit('sort', 'd')">Col D</th>
      <th @click="$emit('sort', 'e')">Col E</th>
      <th @click="$emit('sort', 'chkd')">Chkd</th>
    </thead>
  `
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    coldata: [
      { "a": "Foo", "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 4, "e": 5, "chkd": false},
      { "a": "Bar", "b": 3, "c": 4, "d": 5, "e": 1, "chkd": false },
      { "a": "Baz", "b": 4, "c": 5, "d": 1, "e": 2, "chkd": false },
      { "a": "Daz", "b": 5, "c": 1, "d": 2, "e": 3, "chkd": false }
    ],
    currentSortCol: "a",
    currentSortDir: 'asc',
    currentSortDict: {"a": "desc", "b": "desc", "c": "desc", "d": "desc", "e": "desc"},
    preventSort: false
  },
  methods: {
    sort: function(s) {
      if (this.preventSort) {
        this.preventSort = false;
      }
      //if (s === this.currentSortCol) {
        this.currentSortDict[s] = this.currentSortDict[s]==='asc'?'desc':'asc';
      //}
      this.currentSortCol = s;
      this.currentSortDir = this.currentSortDict[s]
    },
    checkee: function(cs, i) {
        //console.log("len args is " + arguments.length)
        if (this.currentSortCol == "chkd") {
          this.preventSort = true
        }
        else {
          this.preventSort = false
        }
        this.coldata[i].chkd = cs;
    }
  },
  computed: {
    sortedRows: function() {
      if (this.preventSort) {
        return this.coldata;
      }
      return this.coldata.sort((a,b) => {
        let modifier = 1;
        if(this.currentSortDir === "desc") modifier = -1;
        if(a[this.currentSortCol] < b[this.currentSortCol]) return -1 * modifier;
        if(a[this.currentSortCol] > b[this.currentSortCol]) return 1 * modifier;
        return 0;
      });
    }  
  },
});
```

HTML Code

```
<div>
<h3>
foo
</h3>
</div>
<div id="app">
  <h2>Data:</h2>
  <table>
  <head-row @sort="sort"></head-row>
  <tbody>
    <tr is="data-row" v-for="(row, index) in sortedRows"  v-bind:row="row" v-bind:key="row.a" v-bind:index="index" @checkee="checkee">
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

CSS Code

```
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

del {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 420px;
}

td, th {
  width: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap
}
```